# Using Tagged Document and Loops in Gensim

Tags: python, loops, tokenize, word-embedding, doc2vec

I’m in the process of trying to get document similarity values for a corpus of approximately 5,000 legal briefs with `Doc2Vec` (I recognize that the corpus may be a little bit small, but this is a proof-of-concept project for a larger corpus of approximately 15,000 briefs I’ll have to compile later). Being somewhat new to Python, I initially ran into some trouble creating a preprocessing function for the 5,000 text files I have assembled in a folder, but I’ve managed to create one.

The trouble is that, when I used the `Tagged Document` feature to assign a “tag” to each document (“words”), only the text from one of the 5,000 documents (`.txt` files) is used for the “words” portion, and repeats, while the tag (the filename) for each document is used. Basically, one brief is getting tagged 5,000 times, each with a different tag, when I obviously want 5,000 briefs each with a unique tag of its filename.

Below is the code I used. I’m wondering if anyone can help me figure out where I went wrong with this. I don't know if it's a `Tagged Document` feature, or if it's a problem with the loop I created - perhaps I need another within it, or there's some issue with the way I have the loop read the filepath? I'm relatively new to Python, so that's completely possible.

Thank you!

```
briefs = []
BriefList = [p for p in os.listdir(FILEPATH) if p.endswith('.txt')]
for brief in BriefList:
     str = open(FILEPATH + brief,'r').read()
     tokens = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", str)
     tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(tokens, [brief]) for brief in BriefList]
     briefs.append(tagged_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your code, is `len(briefs)` what you expect it to be? Does looking at items like `briefs[0]` or `briefs[-1]` show the individual `TaggedDocument` items you expect?

You probably don't want two nested `for … in` loops - one going over all briefs to open the files, and the other, for each brief, *again* going over all briefs to assign them *all* the same `tokens` value.

Try changing your lines:

```py
     tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(tokens, [brief]) for brief in BriefList]
     briefs.append(tagged_data)
```

...to simply construct & append *one* `TaggedDocument` at a time...

```py
     briefs.append(TaggedDocument(tokens, [brief])
```